# Parsing YYYYMMDDHH-format dates with date from GNU coreutils

Tags: shell, gnu-coreutils

**Not sure if this is duplicate.** If it is kindly point me to the answer.

```
$date  -d '2018022210' +'%Y%m%d%H'
```

Throws me an error saying invalid (`date: invalid date 2018022210`). What is the correct way of doing?

Comment: Invalid *what*?

Comment: invalid date `date: invalid date `2018022210``

Comment: Cross-site dupe: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56824/how-do-you-specify-a-format-for-the-input-to-date

Comment: BSD `date` lets you specify an input format within the confines of the supported components; with GNU `date`, you are limited to a broader, but pre-defined, set of input formats documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Date-input-formats.html.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert to a format GNU date can parse, adding a `T` before the hour will suffice:

```
in='2018022210'
out="${in:0:8}T${in:8}"
date --utc -d "$out"
```

...properly emits:

```
Thu Feb 22 03:00:00 UTC 2018
```

Comment: To do this in simpler POSIX shells like dash (and still GNU date), replace the second line with `out="${in%??}T${in#????????}"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @charles answer. I was also able to parse in a slightly different way as @charles mentioned.

```
date -d "$(echo '2018022210'  | awk '{print substr($1,1,8),substr($1, 9,10)}')" +'%Y%m%d %H'
```